# #define - Expected and Expression C ++

Tags: c++, winapi, syntax-error

I'm writing an application hat will use the same form defaults on most of the forms, so i decided to macro the WNDClASSEX and call it when needed:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef WNDCLASSEX_H
#define WNDCLASSEX_H

#include <windows.h>

//MAIN FORM / LOADER WNDCLASSEX
#define MainLoaderWnd(Size, WindowsProcess, hInstance, Title)\
{\
    return new WNDCLASSEX{\
    size,\
    CS_DBLCLKS,\
    WindowsProcess,\
    0,\
    0,\
    hInstance,\
    LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION),\
    LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW),\
    (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW),\
    NULL,\
    L(Title),\
    LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION)\
};\
}

#endif
```

however, when i add this into the file "loader.cpp", i get the following:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex = MainLoaderWnd(sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), WndProc, hInstance, L"Your Text Here");
//Intellisense error: Expression Expected
```

Ideas/ can't see why his error occurs. :/

Comment: Have you tried compiling? Have you tried getting the result of the preprocessor and reading what the code looks like? The problem with macros (well, one of them) is that you don't really see what the compiler is processing...

Comment: i tryed inlining the function, but it says "No Suitable Constructor exists to convert WNDCLASSEX * to tagWNDClASSEXW"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A preprocessor macro is **not** a function. What the preprocessor does when it sees `MainLoaderWnd` being "called" in your code is to *replace* the "call" with the text in the macro body. This means you assignment will look like this:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex = { return new WNDCLASSEX{ ... }; }
```

This is not a valid assignment.

Instead you could create an `inline` function, which is like a proper function but the compiler (not the preprocessor) may put the generated code *inline* at the place of the call:

```
//MAIN FORM / LOADER WNDCLASSEX
inline PWNDCLASSEX MainLoaderWnd(size_t Size, WNDPROC WindowsProcess,
                                 HINSTANCE hInstance, LPTSTR Title)
{
    PWNDCLASSEX cls = new WNDCLASSEX;

    // Set the fields

    return cls;
}
```